# Retrieving specific data based on sub-child from FireBase - Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data from firebase database based on specific tag which is inside the list of tags. i.e. [image: Below image]

There are two strings inside tags key. Now the problem is that I want to fetch data which has only cricket tag

I tried below code but not working

`Query query = ref.orderByChild("tags").equalTo("cricket");`

Please help. Thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work, you need to denormalize your data, as described in firebase docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data

In your case this would mean to add to your database something like `tags / cricket / dataId1,dataId2,dataId3,...` and then retrieve the list under `ref('tags/cricket')`. You can keep your current links - `data / tags / tag1,tag2,..` and use them when you need to retrieve a list of tags for a data item. Just maintain both of them - there is a multiUpdate functionality to help you set them in a single atomic operation - https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html